# How to regulate sending requests to server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4.1

I need to send many requests to server 50-100 requests to load data, each response has at least 0.5KB and at most 7KB of data.

I send the requests using ajax as following: (code is simplified)

```
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    // make ajax call with element as parameter and update page to show data for element
}
```

This works for my needs, because I dont need data to come from server in order, and it works most of the time. **But** sometimes the last few elements dont get loaded and I get `communication link failure` error in my chrome javascript console.

I am assuming that the server got overloaded, how can I regulate sending requests to make sure I get a response for each request in the shortest time possible?

Notes:

- I use Spring MVC in the backend
- I use ExtJS Ajax to make the requests

Comment: It sounds like you should find a way to turn this into a single AJAX request that sends/receives data for all of the elements at once. Especially since all of the requests happen inside the same for loop; they're already basically linked to eachother.

Comment: @Cuberto, I dont want to do that for 2 reasons. 1) I dont want the user to wait, I want the user to see data coming for each element as soon as possible, and 2) the number of request might grow in the future which will make it extra slow to get all the data at once.

Comment: Could you get data in sections? Such as 10 or so elements at a time? Sending a lot of data per request is much more efficient and less of a strain on your server than sending hundreds of requests at once. Especially if you want to do this in production, you should not be sending too many requests. Remember that every request has overhead such as HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by recursively calling the each request, this way only one request is sent to the server at the time, and overload is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try using seperate loops for your data uploading process. Overloading is the only cause for that Communication failure.

Comment: can you please explain a little more? Not sure what do you mean by separate loops? Also I am downloading data not uploading.

Comment: try using two seperate loops for the downloading/uploading process. servers too get exhausted when a huge pool of date is uploaded/downloaded on them. You can do two things .
1. use partial loops such as for 100 iterations use 2 loops for 50-50 iterations.(this is the concept behind packets(breaking large files in subsequent parts)).
2. You can also try using ajax or js for background downloading process .